# Does Microsoft Essential Business Server 2008 support RDS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

I need to know whether Microsoft Essential Business Server 2008 supports RDS (Remote Desktop Services) a.k.a. Terminal Services. On a separate note (I would accept an answer without it): would I need RDS CALs to access the service?

Comment: I know that SBS doesn't, but I can't find any information on EBS. I suspect they may have the same limitation, but you can try installing the role to find out. You would need CALs. Report back if you find out, this is a good question that could use a searchable answer.

Comment: Was there a Microsoft Essential Business Server 2008? There certainly was a Small Business Server 2008 but I'm not aware of there being a Microsoft Essential Business Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

According to a Microsoft licensing specialist, RDSs are not supported, but there is a different service called "remoteapp" that requires RDS calls.